# Showing message id in body of Mailgun email

Tags: mailgun

Is there a value I can add to an email sent via Mailgun, that Mailgun would replace with their message-id prior to sending?  We have a requirement that a "message id" be visible to the receiver; and if possible we would like to use the Mailgun message-id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019/11/25 mailgun doesn't support this according to a response from support "this feature does not currently exist within our platform".